# Laravel. OrderBy query with last item hasMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

need some help with a query on Laravel(PHP)

what I have :

Two tables. Expedients & ExpedientRevs with a hasMany relationship beetween them.

Expedient Model:

```
  public function ExpedientRevs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ExpedientRev');
  }
```

What I need:
A list of the expedients (Distinct Expedient) order DESC by the last Expedients Revisions (last id of ExpedientRev)

I mean, if I have in ExpedientRev:

```
id     expedient_id  ..........
---   --------------
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         3
5         1
```

My result should be the expedients in this order : 1,3,2 (no duplicated expedients)

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do that;

```php
$expedients = Expedient::orderByDesc(ExpedientRev::select('id')
    ->whereColumn('expedient_revs.expedient_id', 'expedients.id')
    ->latest()
    ->take(1)
)->get();
```

This will get the latest records by ExpedientRev model. If you want to include ExpedientRev in your results. You can use latestOfMany.

In your Expedients model add this one;

```php
public function rev()
{
        return $this->hasOne(ExpedientRev::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

So you can use like this;

```php
$expedients = Expedient::orderByDesc(ExpedientRev::select('id')
    ->whereColumn('expedient_revs.expedient_id', 'expedients.id')
    ->latest()
    ->take(1)
)->with('rev')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The first part works like a charm. sadly the second one doesn't work cause the project is Laravel 6.2 and I cant find the "latestofmany" function in this version. But a great help anyway